# Date range using DAX query in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, dax

I am using SSRS 2015 to create a report. The data is sourced from a tabular cube so I used a DAX query to create the shared dataset. What I am trying to do is add parameters to my report which would allow users to filter the data according to their date range using the calendar picker. I tried:

```
EVALUATE
FILTER(
SUMMARIZE(
  'PurchaseTable'
  ,'PurchaseTable'[Invoice Date]
),
  'PurchaseTable'[Invoice Date] >= DATEVALUE(FORMAT(@FromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy"))
  && 'PurchaseTable'[Invoice Date] <= DATEVALUE(FORMAT(@ToDate, "dd/MM/yyyy"))
)
```

But it produced an error: 
**The following system error occurred: Type mismatch**

I also tried:

```
  'PurchaseTable'[Invoice Date] >= @FromDate
  && 'PurchaseTable'[Invoice Date] <= @ToDate
```

and get the following error: 
**DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Date with values of type Text**

My PurchaseTable[Invoice Date] column is of date type in dd/MM/yyyy format. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: did the suggested answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable with adding parameters to DAX after playing around with SSRS, the following should be the code for your final DAX.

```
EVALUATE(
FILTER(
SUMMARIZE(
  'PurchaseTable'
  ,'PurchaseTable'[Invoice Date]
),
  'PurchaseTable'[Invoice Date] >= VALUE(@FromDate)
  && 'PurchaseTable'[Invoice Date] <= VALUE(@ToDate)
))
```

Make sure that your parameters are always of date type.

Hope this help?

Comment: Happy to help :)